# how to trim quotes and remove special characters from the word in php

Tags: php, string, encoding

how do we trim quotes(single and double). And there are some character like � in some words which i want to remove. How to do it in php. example words i want to reformat

1. poup�e   to poupe or what that � should have been
2. “three to three
3. words" to words

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove these characters rather than set the right encoding so they are displayed correctly?

Comment: I am not understanding how to convert � to correct encoding.

Comment: You don't convert the character to anything. You specify the encoding such that the character is rendered properly.

Answer (score 3):

poup�e should be poupée. As suggested, fix your encoding instead of destroying french words :-)

Comment: Agreed. Hacking away at valid input because you fail to display it correctly is the *wrong fix*!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the quotes with

```
$word=trim($word, '"');
```

Seems to me that the strange characters appear because you have an encoding issue. For solving this, we need to know what kind of encoding do you use in your program, database, and html. I suggest using UTF-8 everywhere, which will basically solve your encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can do it with preg_replace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

and here's an example:

http://www.devdaily.com/php/php-string-strip-characters-whitespace-numbers

Comment: Very tempted to give this a -1; why would you want to use regex ?